# Module or method for handling my scheduling needs?

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8 to build a website that I will use to manage a D&D Campaign. I'm looking for a way to set up session planning.

I would like something where I can create time slots where I am available and then the users can do one of two things:

- Create a proposed session (select a time span within a time slot, add information on what they would like to do - could just be a textbox)
- Join a proposed session (potentially with a cap on # of users per session)

Ideally, I would then be able to approve/deny proposed sessions and have approved sessions block out their time slots.

Is there anything that could work for this? The closest thing I've found would be https://www.drupal.org/project/appointment_calendar but that doesn't look like it would support the ability for multiple proposed sessions or the approve/deny aspect of it.

Or is there a way to make this work with a custom content type or something?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Bookable Entities Everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/bee). It looks rather adapted to what you are looking for, is available to D8 and has a few tutorials to get you started.

Comment: I had come across that one, but saw that it didn't have a stable release yet, that it's still in beta.

Comment: I would recommend to try it out and see if it works for you, there are many modules in alpha or beta that are very high quality in drupal.org.